# Simulating mental disorders in machine learning systems

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Is there any work as the following example in ML:

Suppose a `reinforcement learning` system which has a fixed penalty for every `action`, so there would be a `regret` for taking `action` if the estimated `reward` is wrong most of the time. And suppose the estimated `action values` reach that limit in many iterations, say `agent` estimates there is a `+100` reward in `10` steps ahead, while taking each step has a `-1` reward (`+1` penalty). After taking `10` steps `agent` has a total of `-10` reward and if the `+100` promise comes true, the total sum would be `+100 + (-10) = +90` but in our case that `+100` is wrong most of the times and the true reward would be `-10 + 0 = -10`. This agent will end up taking no action as the `action-value` method is flawed and taking action has a cost. But reaching that point (taking no/little action) takes some iterations.

This is a simple example but now our system is resembling [depression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depression) like seen in humans. Similarly we can simulate `machine mental disorders` (depression, anxiety...) in more complicated settings and studying these problems can help with similar disorders in psychiatry and vice versa.

Is there some related work (links are appreciated)? which keywords should I use for search?

Comment: You might find the paper "Reinforcement Learning, Fast and Slow" interesting. Although they do not discuss mental disorders it provides an understanding of the current discussion to which extend deep (reinforcement) learning can be used as a model of human cognitive processes in neuroscience and cognitive psychology research. Here is the link: https://www.cell.com/trends/cognitive-sciences/fulltext/S1364-6613(19)30061-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look for work on mental disorders and data science you will probably only find things related to real world data which is being analyzed, e.g. predict a mental disorder based on social-economic and medical features of people.

However, your toy example is somewhat similar to the toy examples in chapter "17 Making Complex Decisions" and "21 Reinforcement Learning" in [Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/). While you will not find anything related to your topic in the book, it points in the direction I would focus research on: [intelligent agents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_agent) and related terms to agent theory. That is probably a more promising direction of research than "data science" or "machine learning" here.

As a side note: I would keep in mind that psychological models of mental disorders itself are an active area of research. You could, for example, look into a reinforcement learning agent to investigate learned self-helplessness as a potential cause of clinical depression. However, learned self-helplessness as a cause of clinical depression has, to my knowledge, not been fully validated in clinical psychology yet and is only one psychological model among others.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your question deserves so many downvotes, but I can understand (well guess at least) why ML experts don't see it as a legitimate question:

- It's a bit naive: while ML has concepts such as reinforcement, reward, cost etc., and of course these terms are derived from their respective meaning in the general language, but in the ML context these have a specific formal meaning. In particular they are not meant to be assigned hard-coded values like you suggest.
- In the same idea, ML requires a precise, formal representation of concepts. What would be an action in this context? How would you represent an agent/person, and the interactions between them?
- Currently as far as I can see what you propose is a kind of simulation involving predefined mechanisms, there's no actual data involved. The only way to evaluate this would be to compare against real cases whether the simulation ends with the same results, and that would also be difficult to formalize properly.

In my opinion why not? It could be an interesting idea, but there are a lot of details to clarify, and I suspect that psychological disorders are not the easiest thing to represent accurately in a formal setting.

Comment: I'm used to `downvotes` but no one provided a reason! Yes I'm new to `ML` and found `RL`  interesting. After reading the basics of `RL` I thought of how such systems can become ill (stuck at achieving the goal) in the sense we call it `mental disorder` in medicine. Solutions to such problems can be used in the other discipline.I'm not enough expert to formalize the idea in the provided example that's why I'm looking for any related work (post, paper, book, etc).